# Example of equivalent linear transformations with different rank

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

As stated in title. When it comes to infinite dimensional vector spaces I guess I just lose track. Can somebody give me an example of equivalent linear transformations with different rank?

[EDIT]: What I am saying is that are there two linear transformations $S,T: U \rightarrow V$ such that $S=PTQ$ for some isomorphisms $P:V\rightarrow V, Q:U\rightarrow U$, but with $dim(im(S))\ne dim(im(T))$.
I think this only works in infinitely dimensional vector space.

Comment: It's not clear to me what you're asking.  The *rank* of a linear transformation between vector spaces is the dimension of the image.  If both the domain and codomain of a map are infinite dimensional, then the rank can be infinite (although it doesn't have to be).

Comment: As far as I can gather the only way to do this would be the tame transformation in a different basis

Answer (score 1):

This isn't possible.  If $P$ and $Q$ are isomorphisms and $S=PTQ$, then $P$ restricts to an isomorphism from the image of $T$ to the image of $S$, so they have the same dimension.  To prove this, take any $v=Tu$ in the image of $T$.  Then $Pv=PTQ(Q^{-1}u)=S(Q^{-1}u)$, so $Pv$ is in the image of $S$.  Thus $P$ restricts to a linear map $\operatorname{im}(T)\to\operatorname{im}(S)$, which is injective since $P$ is.  To see that this map is surjective, if $v=Su$ is in the image of $S$, then $v=P(TQu)$ is $P$ of something in the image of $T$.

Comment: I don't think P necessarily induce an isomorphism from image of T to image of S, in the infinite dimensional case.

Comment: I have added more details.

Comment: Yeah that makes perfect sense... Then I guess the problem is harder than I think... Is there any way to show that two linear transformations have the same rank but are not equivalent? Or more generally, how to show that two linear transformations are not equivalent (no such invertible maps P and Q)?

Comment: Yes, in the infinite-dimensional case you can have two maps which have the same rank and are not equivalent.  For a simple example, let $U=V$ have basis $\{e_n\}_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$, let $S$ be the identity map, and let $T$ send each $e_n$ to $e_{n+1}$.  Then both $S$ and $T$ have (countably) infinite rank, but $S$ is surjective and $T$ is not, so they cannot be equivalent.  (In the infinite-dimensional case, to get a criterion for equivalence, you need to consider both the dimension and the codimension of the image, not just the dimension.)

Comment: Yeah I didn't think of it in terms of surjectivity! By exact terms of definition of equivalence it is really hard to reason... Thank you so much!